# Insert - after every second Character

Tags: c#, regex, character

so I'm developimg a Game with Unity 3D using C#. As first step the user has to enter his personal Code, which consists of 5 pairs, where each pairs has 2 characters/numbers (Im validating the characters & numbers separately). Now what I'm trying to achieve is that after every second character there should appear a minus, like you have after every 4th number, when you enter your credit-card number.

Example: 27-05-AB-CD-EF

So now I tried to use a Regular Expression and its working for the first two letters, but somehow the Regex does see the minus as a character too, and then it adds a minus infinitely often. I tried different versions, where i thought that i just allow letters and numbers, but somehow that doesn't work.

```
Regex.Replace(codeText, "([A-Za-z0-9][^-]){2}", "$0-");
```

Any guess what might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have `27-05-AB-CD-EF` as output if `27-05-AB-CD-EF` is input? Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"\w{2}(?=[^-])", "$0-")`. The regex can also look like `@"[^\W_]{2}(?=[^-])"` if you do not want to match `_`s.

Comment: `"(([A-Za-z0-9]){2}[^-])"` ? (2 characters a-Z0-9 not being lead by a -) With this you will get something like `27-05-AB-CD-EF-`

Comment: If you have 5 strings and you want one use `string.Join("-",pairs)`

Comment: To clarify, my input is without minus, and I want to call Regex.Replace after every new character. Also this is 1 Inputfield, which is 1 String.

Comment: @MartinPfeifhofer I have no idea what you are talking about, there is no 'cursor' in your question. Post the code you have problems with.

Comment: @MartinPfeifhofer it depends on what kind of control you are using to display the text. If it's a TextBox you need to set CaretIndex to text.Length

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry i meaned caret not cursor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this expression `"([A-Za-z0-9]){2}(?!-)"` where `(?!-)` is a Zero-width negative lookahead assertion which in case you don't know is an expression that is matched but isn't part of the match value. So this expression matches two characters that aren't followed by -.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html read this page for more information

Comment: This is almost doing the job, just like the answer of @Wiktor Stribiżew. The only addition, was that I had to move the caret-position to the last position in the Inputfield.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually it is not the same solution, your solution is slightly better, because it doesn't insert another - after all the 10 characters have been entered.